# Error on ClientContext

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model

When I try to get sub sites of specific sub site

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext('/groupcompanies');
var webs = clientContext.get_web().get_webs();
```

I get this error:

> undefined is not a function >>>>> sp.js

While

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

works fine, there is always a problem when I define a url for `ClientContext`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext('/groupcompanies');
```

is incorrect, you need to create a new context, like this:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('/groupcompanies');
```

(Notice the `new` keyword). Also make sure that `/groupcompanies` is a valid server relative path to a web.

Comment: It will be nice if u explain why SP.ClientContext.get_current() works without new keyword ?

Comment: Mainly because that is a contextual variable to have with you all the time (compare to the CurrentContext in server side code). When you want to create a context for another site you do not have that context and hence need to create a new object for that context.